# Python: How to find most common elements of a list of files

Tags: python, optimization, coding-style

first of all sorry for the easy question, but i cannot figure out the easiest way to code my problem.

I have a directory with several different file but with common elements (the values_25,_26,_28, etc.) as:

```
xxxxx_25.txt
xxxxx_26.txt
xxxxx_27.txt
xxxxx_28.txt
yyyyy_25.txt
yyyyy_26.txt
yyyyy_27.txt
yyyyy_29.txt
mmmmm_25.txt
mmmmm_26.txt
mmmmm_27.txt
mmmmm_30.txt
```

I wish to get lists as

```
xxxxx_25.txt
yyyyy_25.txt
mmmmm_25.txt

xxxxx_26.txt
yyyyy_26.txt
mmmmm_26.txt

xxxxx_27.txt
yyyyy_27.txt
mmmmm_27.txt

xxxxx_28.txt

yyyyy_29.txt

mmmmm_30.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is well defined -- Why not group them all based on the fact that they all end in `.txt`?

Comment: @Gianni: next time, specify *exactly* what do you expect at the output  - I do not know if you need flat list, or nested list, if ordering of prefixes does matter etc..

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

list_with_file_names = 'xxxx_25.txt xxxxx_26.txt xxxxx_27.txt xxxxx_28.txt yyyyy_25.txt yyyyy_26.txt yyyyy_27.txt yyyyy_29.txt mmmmm_25.txt mmmmm_26.txt mmmmm_27.txt mmmmm_30.txt'.split()

def get_number_and_prefix(text):
    g = re.match('.*(\S+)(\d+)', text)
    return tuple([
        int(g.group(2)),
        g.group(1)])

nice_list = sorted(list_with_file_names, key=get_number_and_prefix)
```

Tuples returned from `get_number_and_prefix` will be sorted first by the number, and later by the prefix

If, instead, you want to group based on the number in filename, you can use something like this:

```
def update_dict_with_file(dict_, filename):
    g = re.match('.*(\d+)', filename)
    key = g.group(1)
    t = dict_.setdefault(key,[])
    t.append(filename)

mydict = {}
[update_dict_with_file(mydict, filename) 
 for filename in list_with_file_names]
```

`mydict` now contains numbers from file names as keys, and lists with file names as values

**Edit**

To summarise all the answers until now, all you need is to build a `sorted` list out of your list, using a key getter function that extracts whatever you want from your filenames. You can do it by either fancy one-liner with `itertools` + list comprehension, or a lengthier `for` loop (no `yield`anywhere?). But, basically, they are all the same. No rocket science.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
list_of_files = [
    'xxxxx_25.txt',
    'xxxxx_26.txt',
    'xxxxx_27.txt',
    'xxxxx_28.txt',
    'yyyyy_25.txt',
    'yyyyy_26.txt',
    'yyyyy_27.txt',
    'yyyyy_29.txt',
    'mmmmm_25.txt',
    'mmmmm_26.txt',
    'mmmmm_27.txt',
    'mmmmm_30.txt',
    ]

import re
regex = re.compile('_([0-9]+)\.txt$')

def keyfn(name):
    match = regex.search(name)
    if match is None:
        return None
    else:
        return match.group(1)

import itertools
for (key, group) in itertools.groupby(sorted(list_of_files,key=keyfn),keyfn):
    print [x for x in group]
```

or if you want a list of lists as a result, replace the `for` loop with:

```
[x for g in itertools.groupby(sorted(list_of_files,key=keyfn),keyfn) for x in g[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#Considering your list of files is as follows
ur_file_list = """xxxxx_25.txt
xxxxx_26.txt
xxxxx_27.txt
xxxxx_28.txt
yyyyy_25.txt
yyyyy_26.txt
yyyyy_27.txt
yyyyy_29.txt
mmmmm_25.txt
mmmmm_26.txt
mmmmm_27.txt
mmmmm_30.txt"""
#Based on the pattern, you can get the key assuming, you need the part in the
#filename (without ext) after underscore. So this will give you the part without regex
key = lambda e: os.path.splitext(e)[0].split("_")[-1]
from itertools import groupby
#On a sorted list, group on the above key function
#And generate a list of these groups
[list(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted(ur_file_list.splitlines(), key = key), key = key)]
[['xxxxx_25.txt', 'yyyyy_25.txt', 'mmmmm_25.txt'], ['xxxxx_26.txt', 'yyyyy_26.txt', 'mmmmm_26.txt'], ['xxxxx_27.txt', 'yyyyy_27.txt', 'mmmmm_27.txt'], ['xxxxx_28.txt'], ['yyyyy_29.txt'], ['mmmmm_30.txt']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) comes in very handy for this task.

```
In [1]: import re; from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: filenames
Out[2]: 
['xxxxx_25.txt',
 'xxxxx_26.txt',
 'xxxxx_27.txt',
 'xxxxx_28.txt',
 'yyyyy_25.txt',
 'yyyyy_26.txt',
 'yyyyy_27.txt',
 'yyyyy_29.txt',
 'mmmmm_25.txt',
 'mmmmm_26.txt',
 'mmmmm_27.txt',
 'mmmmm_30.txt']

In [3]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for filename in filenames:
  ....:     m = re.search(r'_(\d+)\.txt$', filename)
  ....:     if m:
  ....:         d[m.group(1)].append(filename)

In [5]: [sorted(filename_list) for filename_list in d.values()]
Out[5]: 
[['xxxxx_25.txt', 'yyyyy_25.txt'],
 ['mmmmm_26.txt', 'xxxxx_26.txt', 'yyyyy_26.txt'],
 ['mmmmm_27.txt', 'yyyyy_27.txt'],
 ['xxxxx_28.txt'],
 ['yyyyy_29.txt'],
 ['mmmmm_30.txt']]
```